# Scrapy pipeline is enabled but never used

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to add a pipeline to my scrapy project.  I have a spider that yields items successfully. I can see them displayed in the log once they are yielded with no errors.  Scrapy says that my pipeline is enabled but when I put a simple print argument in the pipeline it never prints.

my pipeline file:

```
class SurefirebPipeline:
    def drop_empty_odds(self, item, spider):
        print("We are in the pipeline")
        return item
```

my settings file

```
BOT_NAME = 'sfb'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['sfb.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'sfb.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
   'sfb.middlewares.SurefirebSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    'sfb.middlewares.SurefirebDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}    
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
        'sfb.pipelines.SurefirebPipeline': 900,
    }
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Comment: `drop_empty_odds` is not an item pipeline method. Why do you expect it to be called?

Comment: How can it be called? I am new to scrapy but I thought I did it just how the docs had it.

Comment: You should read https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline , I think you are looking for the `process_item` method.

Comment: Am I not able to rename process item to whatever I want?

Comment: Nope, it’s a callback. You may call another method from it, but renaming will prevent it from being called.

Comment: That worked!  But how can I have multiple methods in one pipeline?

Comment: You can call other methods from `process_item`. If that’s not what you meant, please elaborate.